# Updating Model from View on MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

We have an ordering form that has a lot of fields to fill out. We also use Kendo UI.

This is an example of what 1 out of at least 100 fields (all in the same view).

```
<div style="text-align: center; margin-top: 1em; margin-bottom: 1em;">
    <label class="inputLabel" for="client_name" style="display: inline-block;">PON :</label>
    @(Html.Kendo().TextBoxFor(m => m.asrDTO.ASRForm.adminSection.PON)
     .Name("pon")
     .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "display: inline-block; border: 1px solid #BCBDBC" })
     )
</div>
```

Our controller gets the value from the database and stores it in our HomeModel which we use to pass the values inside the "TextBoxFor".

```
@model ASROrderingUtility.Models.HomeModel
```

And this is our controller simplified:

```
HomeModel asrDTOModel = new HomeModel();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ASRUOMProcessService.getTransportOrderDTO request = new ASRUOMProcessService.getTransportOrderDTO();
            request.sT1BTN = "ORDERNUMBER";
            asrDTOModel.asrDTO = getASRProcessService().getTransportOrderDTO(request).@return;
            return View(asrDTOModel);
        }
```

But since there are so many fields, we were curious to see if there is a quick way to update the model without having to write an extremely long AJAX or JS method.

So my question is: Suppose every field is updated by the user, and they click the save button at the end. Is there a way to refresh/bind/update all the fields back in the Model, thus avoiding writing a very long AJAX/JS method?

Comment: There are various ways to do this. Explain your method? What do you mean by "avoiding writing a very long AJAX/JS method"?

Comment: Well since I have over 100 fields to update to the model, I was wondering if there was a piece of code that just updates all those fields back into the model.

Comment: Basically a bulk procedure that can be done in few lines of code.

Comment: option1: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/  Option2: User JS frameworks like KnockoutJS or AngularJS which provides Two-way data binding

Comment: Do you want to do update by jq or by submitting the view?

Comment: `$('form').serialize()` will serialize all the form controls in your form

Comment: Thanks guys, I will try those.

Comment: @Hadee Either one is fine, the shorter the better. Like mentioned on the post above, it's a huge form.

Comment: I prefer modelview and using model binding for submitting the form.